# How to find the conjugate of $\sum_{n=0}^{m}n \cos(2\pi x n)$?

Tags: complex-numbers, summation, fourier-series

Supposing I want to find the conjugate of

$$\tag{1}\label{eq1}\sum_{n=0}^{m}n \cos(2\pi x n)$$

If I view (1) as a Fourier series then what would be the conjugate Fourier series and how would I go about doing so?

If I first change the cosine using the identity $\cos (ax) = \frac{1}{2} (e^{iax}+e^{-iax})$ would that make \eqref{eq2}?

$$\sum_{n=0}^{m}\frac{n}{2} (e^{i2\pi x}+e^{-i2\pi x})\tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

then could I simply from $\psi=Ae^{i(kx-\omega t)}+ Be^{-i(kx+\omega t)}$ using identity [$\bar{\psi} = \bar{A} \mathrm{e}^{-i (k x - \omega t)} + \bar{B} \mathrm{e}^{i (k x + \omega t)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95598/complex-conjugate-of-function)

do this?

$$\sum_{n=0}^{m}\frac{n}{2} (e^{-i2\pi x}+e^{i2\pi x})\tag{3}\label{eq3}$$

So I suppose from \eqref{eq3} if my working is correct we end up where we begun?

Comment: Is $x$ real? If so, then the entire sum is real so conjugating it won't change anything.

Comment: Your summation is a real number without imaginary part. So its complex conjugate is itself.

Comment: okay guys thanks for sorting that out oh and for the downvote that's really a bonus for me and anybodyelse that might try to do what I have done:)

Comment: maybe you want the conjugate Fourier series which is quite a different story from the complex conjugate

Comment: @Conrad yes that's what I actually want but to conjugate the Fourier series which is shown in (1) I'd have to know the original function (which I do not know) or take an inverse Fourier series and then perform the conjugate on the original function and then take the fourier series. Unless you know a better way to do this directly on (1)?

Comment: Definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_Fourier_series.

Comment: @Martín-Blas Pérez Pinilla  I had seen that but maybe it suggests the cosine in (1) becomes sine so the conjugate becomes $\sum_{n=0}^{m}n \sin(2\pi x n)$ - so I was not sure

Answer (score 1):

Using the Wikipedia definition, as $a_n = n$ and $b_n = 0$, the conjugate series will be
$$\sum_{n=1}^m n\sin(2\pi x n).$$

Comment: it's also an easy check to show $f+ig$ analytic, where $f$ is the original function and $g$ the one above, and satisfy oneself that the definition works